# Why exception is not properly caught?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, try-catch

I have a piece of code.

```
import sys

while(True):
  print "Enter a number: "
  try:
    number = int(sys.stdin.readline())
  except ValueError:
    print "Error! Enter again an integer value"
    continue
  finally:
    print number
    break
```

Here I expect when I enter a non-integer number, the output should be

`Error! Enter again an integer value`

and then it should ask for input. But it is printing the message but asking for further inputs. Please explain it or if am thinking it wrong.

**If I handle with NameError, then error message is not even being printed and the program is exiting with a traceback call.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finally` clause *always* runs, whether an exception was caught or not.  You want `else`, which runs when there was *no* exception.

Also: you don't need parentheses for a `while`, and you probably want the `raw_input` function which is a little nicer to use than messing with `sys.stdin` directly.

So I would do:

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "Error! Enter again an integer value"
        continue
    else:
        print number
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `finally` should be `else`, otherwise it will execute regardless of whether or not there was an exception.